# BLKID doesn't show external hdd UUID

Tags: mount, hard-drive, automount, uuid

On my raspberry Pi, I am using two external HDDs. OS is Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS.

The first one is a small WD elements that automount perfectly well (USB connected)

The second one is a big WD drive with an external power supply (USB connected). With this last one, I have to restart the drive each time I reboot the Pi. Otherwise, I don't see it in the terminal and can't mount it. Once restarted, with lsblk, I see it, but with blkid, I don't. I don't have an UUID and cannot automount it.

Any help???

Comment: Using what OS? Ubuntu or Pi?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Please edit the question and add this info.

Comment: If the device was absent during initial probing, you may need to force blkid to ignore the default cache file, i.e. `blkid -c /dev/null`

Comment: Find the messages dealing with the 2nd drive in `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. They may help.